# Angular CLI - run script on build using environment value

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-2

I have been tasked with including a JSON file with my Angular 2 CLI application that contains settings for the app to use based on the environment that it is deployed to.

I am trying to create / modify this file during the ng build process.  The idea is that I will be able to modify values in the JSON file if necessary without doing a rebuild of the whole application.

My environment.env.ts file will look like this:

```
export const environment = {
    mySetting: "envSetting"
};
```

...and my custom-app-config.json file after 'ng build -e "env"' will look like this:

```
{
    "mySetting": "envSetting"
}
```

I can output the file correctly using the angular-cli.json setting:

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "custom-app-config.json"
  ],
```

...but I cannot find anywhere to put a script to modify the custom-app-config.json file before it gets copied to the dist directory.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.